# Why do we calculate the complexity of recursive programs?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity

we know that complexity of a program same either it is written in recursive manner or iterative manner, we can calculate its complexity from its iterative(loops) program, why do we need to calculate the complexity of its recursive structure?
we know it gives same complexity for the both of the methods. 
E.g, I have seen that,

- Complexity of Iterative algorithm of Factorial is O(n) and Complexity
  of Recursive algorithm of Factorial is also O(n).

  Complexity of Iterative algorithm of Binary Search is O(logn) and
  Complexity of Recursive algorithm of Binary Search is also O(logn).

  why do we need to calculate of complexity of recursive programs, if
  we know the complexities of their iterative algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an iterative program it is easy to translate it to recursive program conserving the complexity. But the converse it not true! You have functions that can't be computed by iterations only by recursion (the most famous is the [Ackerman function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function)).

So the general case is the recursion not iteration.

Comment: "Ackermann function cannot be expressed without recursion" This is not true. How do you think recursion is implemented in a computer? The CPU operates iteratively on a sequence of instructions. To support function calls, including recursive calls, it manages a stack. Using recursion is simply letting the language (OS, runtime, etc.) manage a stack for you. Any recursive algorithm can be replaced with an iterative one where you manage the stack yourself, including Ackermann. –

Comment: Well you miss the point about recursion, if you use a call stack then you are using recursion. Becareful these things are very subtle. You can hide call stack in very subtle ways, but that doesn't make the program iterative.